How much information can be transferred via a given 2-qudit gate?
Suppose Alice and Bob want to send some (classical) information to each other via the following scheme: there is a quantum system consisting of 2 qudits $A$ and $B$ (both have dimension $d$), with Hilbert space $H=H_A\otimes H_B$. Alice can prepare whatever initial state $|\psi_a\rangle$ for qudit $A$, and Bob can prepare whatever initial state $|\phi_b\rangle$ for qudit $B$, and the initial state of the whole system is a product state $|\Psi\rangle=|\psi_a\rangle\otimes |\phi_b\rangle$. Then the whole system undergoes a unitary evolution $\hat{U}$ which is known to both Alice and Bob, and the state evolves to   $|\Psi'\rangle=\hat{U}|\Psi\rangle$, as shown in the figure below. After the evolution, Alice can make whatever measurement $\hat{P}$ on $A$ and Bob can make whatever measurement $\hat{Q}$ on $B$. Note that no direct communication happens between Alice and Bob throughout the experiment. I wonder how much information can be transfered between Alice and Bob in this way, for a given $\hat{U}$.

We can formulate this problem using a game. Before the game begins, a Referee generates a Haar random unitary $\hat{U}\in SU(d^2)$, and let both Alice and Bob know about $\hat{U}$, and Alice and Bob are allowed to discuss a winning strategy. After the game begins, any form of direct communication between Alice and Bob is prohibited. The Referee randomly generates two numbers $a,b\in\{1,2,\ldots,d\}$ and gives $a$ to Alice, and $b$ to Bob. Then they are allowed to manipulate the 2-qudit quantum system as described above (the unitary evolution $\hat{U}$ is controlled by the Referee). At the end of the game, the Referee asks Alice about $b$ and asks Bob about $a$, and they win if they both answer correctly. Alice can encode the number $a$ in the initial state $|\psi_a\rangle$ she prepares, and similarly for Bob. Then from the result of the measurements, they should be able to obtain some clue about each other's number.
Question: what strategy should they use to maximize their chance of success and how big is the change of success for a (Haar) randomly generated $\hat{U}$?
